# BeautifulSoup and urllib to find data from website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

### Background

I am trying to understand the process in which specific data can be extracted from a website using `beautifulsoup4` and `urllib` libraries.

How would I get the specific price of a DVD from a website, if:

- The div class is `<div class="productPrice" data-component="productPrice">`
- The p class is `<p class="productPrice_price" data-product-price="price">£9.99 </p>`

### Code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("https://www.zavvi.com/dvd/rampage-includes-digital-download/11729469.html ")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), features='html.parser')

all_divs = bsObj.find_all('div', {'class':'productPrice'}) # 1. get all divs
```

What is the remaining process of finding the price?

Website (https://www.zavvi.com/dvd/rampage-includes-digital-download/11729469.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, just one more step. You just need to loop through the elements and find the `<p>` tag, with class="productPrice_price", and grab the text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("https://www.zavvi.com/dvd/rampage-includes-digital-download/11729469.html ")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), features='html.parser')

all_divs = bsObj.find_all('div', {'class':'productPrice'}) # 1. get all divs 

for ele in all_divs:
    price = ele.find('p', {'class':'productPrice_price'}).text
    print (price)
```

**Output:**

```
£9.99
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand the process of finding data better :)

Comment: ya once you get the hang of it, you start see the pattern. if this worked out, be sure to accept the answer